# Как запретить автоматическую сортировку при добавлении записи в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Можно ли как-то предотвратить обновление сортировки при редактировании записи?
слетает указатель с редактируемой записи при нажатии button, тем самым сохраняет данные той ячейки которая была выше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На [большом СО предложили хак](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8086011/293099): добавить скрытую колонку `SORT_ORDER`, не привязанную к данным, и при сортировке копировать в неё данные из колонки, по которой идёт сортировка. Уведомление об изменениях отключается, чтобы избежать интерпретации этого копирования как реального редактирования.

Вопрос вообще-то про редактирование, а не про добавление, но, думаю, можно адаптировать (задавать колонке подходящее значение, чтобы строка оказывалась в нужной позиции).

```
private void MyDataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
    dirtyCellListenerEnabled = false;

    SORT_ORDER.ValueType = MyDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ValueType;

    foreach(DataGridViewRow r in MyDataGridView.Rows) {
        r.Cells[SORT_ORDER.Index].Value = r.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
    }

    switch(MyDataGridView.SortOrder) {
        case System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.None:
            MyDataGridView.Sort(SORT_ORDER, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending:
            MyDataGridView.Sort(SORT_ORDER, ListSortDirection.Descending);
            break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending:
            MyDataGridView.Sort(SORT_ORDER, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            break;
    }
    dirtyCellListenerEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли